# Which class should take care of shortcuts?

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm coding a simple text editor with only few basic features.
At the moment it has a `QMainWindow` with `QTabWidget` set as it's `centralWidget`.
What I'm implementing now are some shortcuts; `ctrl+s` to save, `ctrl+o` to open, and `ctrl+t/ctrl+w` to create a new tab/close the current tab.

I know how to implement all the features, but the question is **where** to implement the features?
Should all the shortcuts be members of `QMainWindow` and let it take care of everything, or should I try separating the shortcuts into their correspoding classes?
For example, creating a new tab (`ctrl+t`) would be part of `QTabWidget`.
Now what about `ctrl+s` (save, duh), should it be part of `QTextEdit` since it's the text I'm saving, or..?

Basically my program contains three classes; `QMainWindow`, which contains `QTabWidget`, and each tab is a `QTextEdit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup sounds a lot like many of the applications I've built.

I generally handle shortcuts via the [`QAction::setShortcut()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qaction.html#shortcut-prop) method, so it's really more about where does it make sense to store the `QAction` objects.  This usually ends up being my MainWindow class as a lot of the actions are all used in the MainWindw's menus. When these actions are triggered, the result is usually that the TabWidget is notified which in turn notifies all the necessary tabs and can handle things like a "Close All" action triggering only one save prompt.

However, if it doesn't make sense to store those `QAction`s on the MainWindow object, then I don't, as in the case of the context menu I usually have available on my individual tabs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not **exactly** what I was after, but it helped me enough to realize what I needed ^^ Thanks, got it all figured out now!